# Преобразование порядкового номера дня в году в дату

Tags: веб-программирование, php

У меня есть порядковый номер дня в году и его нужно преобразовать в дату.
например номер 35 - это 4 февраля, 92 - 4 апреля. Подскажите функцию какой такое можно сделать, ну или хотя бы приблизительный алгоритм.

Answer (score 5):

В PHP:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');   // Задаем год
$date->add(new DateInterval('P51D')); // Добавляем к значению года 51 день
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";   // 2000-02-21
?>
```

В MySQL:

```
SELECT MAKEDATE(2000, 51) # 51 - номер дня, 2000 - год
```

Comment: красота, конечно))) только DateTime встроенный сначала "оживить", что у меня в своё время не получилось :(

Answer (score 3):

Прошу прощенья, не подумал. Даже можно еще проще без `strtotime()`:

```
$day = 35;
echo date("c", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, $day, 2012));
```

Comment: опередил на 15 секунд ))

Answer (score 3):

Так не пробовали?

```
$z = 61;
$y = 2012;
echo date("d.m.Y",strtotime("+$z day",mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, $y)));
```

Ну а **`d.m.Y`** можете поменять уже на свое.
Если **$z == 0**, то вернет последний день предидущего года.

Comment: только $z за кавычки вынесите ;) И будет полная радость интерпретатору)

Comment: Интерпретатору и с кавычками неплохо :)

Comment: 2 @kemerov4anin:

Кавычки то двойные.

Comment: Да пофигу, конкатенация строк (читай "вынос переменных за кавычки") ускоряет работу

Comment: Любитель экономить на спичках?

Answer (score 0):

Либо вариант с тем, чтобы 51 день самому к началу года прибавить: 51*(24*60*60) и оттуда вычислять